# regex when underlying structure is different r

Tags: regex, r

I have a output that looks as follows(sample):

```
 [1] "  360<e8>_ Tank Top Gas Portable Heater"                                           " 180<e8>_ Pir-Incandescent-CFL-LED Occupancy Detector - White"                    
 [3] " 90<e8>_  Angle Bracket - Silver Galvanized"                                       " Professional 90<e8>_  Tube Bender"
```

However, when I check the structure, I get the following:

```
str(samp)
 chr [1:26] "  360\xe8_ Tank Top Gas Portable Heater" " 180\xe8_ Pir-Incandescent-CFL-LED Occupancy Detector - White" " 90\xe8_  Angle Bracket - Silver Galvanized"
```

I am trying to replace '_' and other similar looking unicode characters with blank.

I tried the following:

```
str_extract(samp, '\\<(.*?)_')
```

and it returns NA.

However, when I try the following:

```
vec1 <- c('360<e8>_ Tank Top ', 'Professional 90<e8>_  Tube', 'AR30S Retail Optics 36<U+FFFD>_ LED', '45<U+3E38653C>_ Sch.', 'Connectors 341 Tan _x000D_')
str_extract(vec1, '\\<(.*?)_')
```

I get the following output which I would want out of my 'samp'

```
[1] "<e8>_"         "<e8>_"         "<U+FFFD>_"     "<U+3E38653C>_" NA
```

So, I can do comparison only when I create a vector. In that case, how I do comparison when the underlying structure of my sample is different than what it shows when printed?

Any inputs on how to deal with this?

Comment: If you want to replace, why use `str_extract`? Use `str_replace_all`, or just `gsub`. Something like `gsub("<[^_]+", " ", samp)`. That would work with string data.

Comment: I would be using gsub() eventually. I used str_extract to show how the results differ across 'samp' and 'vec1'. I tried using gsub("<[^_]+", " ", samp) and that did not work. Problem is that the underlying structure is different for samp. Example: '360<e8>_ ' is actually represented as '360\xe8_ '(first example: look at the print vs str() output). Hence, using '<' in regex is not going to give an output.

Comment: Ok, if you really want to remove the non-ASCII, try `gsub("[^[:ascii:]]+", " ", samp)`. Again, that might not work with the type of data you have, but it would work with string data.

Comment: thanks! I tried:  `gsub("[^[:alnum:]]+", " ", samp)`  and the first element changed from: `"  360<e8>_ Tank Top Gas Portable Heater"` to `" 360 Tank Top Gas Portable Heater"`. However, I want to actually replace '<e8>_' with word 'deg'. Do you have idea on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use gsub.

```
gsub('<.*?_', '', samp)
```

or

```
gsub('[^[:print:]]*_', '', samp)
```

`[^[:print:]]*` helps to match non-printable characters.

Comment: That would not work since the underlying structure is different. Example: '360<e8>_ ' is actually represented as '360\xe8_ '(first example: look at the print vs str() output). Hence, using '<' in regex is not going to give an output.

Comment: @CraigBing then remove the starting `<` . And also `_` is followed by a space character, so.. `gsub('[^[:print:]]*_(?=\s|$)', '', samp, perl=T)`

Comment: thanks! But, I tried `gsub('[^[:print:]]*_(?=\s|$)', '', samp, perl=T)` in R and it returned: `Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'[^[:print:]]*_(?=\s"`. So, I tried: `gsub('[^[:print:]]*_(?=\\s|$)', '', samp, perl=T)` and it returned: `Error in gsub("[^[:print:]]*_(?=\\s|$)", "", samp, perl = T) : 
  input string 1 is invalid UTF-8` Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok..I tried: `gsub('[^[:print:]]*_', ' degree ', samp, perl=F)` and that did the trick...thanks for your answer!